# Create an entry to a REST API with post

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm struggling a bit within a small project for fetching and creating (via POST) an entry, where I have on one side:

- A GraphQL server (apollo)
- A react app, using useQuery hook
- A rest API, where the resolvers of the Apollo project is fetching data with async JS functions

I have the following obstacles:
I'm not able to post an entry for the rest API via GraphQl query or Mutation.
I have success in this post request:

```
POST https://technologytalents.io/space-cats/index.php/openapi/create_channel_entry
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: axios/0.21.1

channel_id=1&url_title=Blas&entry_date=12345678&title=Dooom&session_id=b288ea559b20c584a3a793685ceb20c240c26569
```

The success response of this is:

`{entry_id: 2}`

In my graphQL schema:

```
input entryIntput {
        url_title: String
        title: String
        channel_id: Int
        entry_date: Int
    }
type postEntrySuccess {
        entry_id: Int
    }

type Mutation {
        createEntry(input: entryIntput): postEntrySuccess
    }
```

and in the resolvers:

```
Mutation: {
    createEntry: async (_, entry) => await channelEntriesService.postEntry(entry)
  }
```

my ChannelEntriesSerives looks like:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const authenticate = require('./authenticate')

class ChannelEntries {

  constructor(options) {
    this._options = options
  }

  async getEntries() {
    const auth = await authenticate.auth()

    const patch = {
      ...options,
      url: `${options.url}/get_channel_entries?channel_id=1&where[status]=open&session_id=${auth.session_id}`
    }

    const response = await axios(patch)

    return response.data
  }

  async postEntry(entry = { url_title: 'Blas', title: 'Dooom', entry_date: Date.now(), channel_id: 1 }) {
    const auth = await authenticate.auth()

    const patch = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      url: `${this._options.url}/create_channel_entry?channel_id=${entry.channel_id}&url_title=${entry.url_title}&title=${entry.title}&entry_date=${entry.entry_date}_id=${auth.session_id}`
    }
    const response = await axios.request(patch)

    return response.data
  }
}

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://technologytalents.io/space-cats/index.php/openapi',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
}

module.exports = instance = new ChannelEntries(options)
```

When I try to execute the mutation on the GraphQl studio:

```
mutation CreateEntry($createEntryInput: entryIntput) {
  createEntry(input: $createEntryInput) {
    entry_id
  }
}
```

I've got an error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createEntry"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "config": {
            "url": "https://technologytalents.io/space-cats/index.php/openapi/create_channel_entry?channel_id=undefined&url_title=undefined&title=undefined&entry_date=undefined_id=b3c77d7c74b0cc10de61c90f8e1a34b30e454f7a",
            "method": "post",
            "headers": {
              "Accept": "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              "User-Agent": "axios/0.21.1"
            },
            "transformRequest": [
              null
            ],
            "transformResponse": [
              null
            ],
            "timeout": 0,
            "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
            "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
            "maxContentLength": -1,
            "maxBodyLength": -1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "createEntry": null
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 2nd resover arg is args, object with variables, not one arg ... missing `&` in url

Comment: I can't find missing & in the urls

Comment: Ops, sorry - I found it. Also, the args need destructuring as you noted.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the error, and this is due to my rusty Axios basics. The config of an Axios request should have "data" property, so changing it to

```
const patch = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      url: `${this._options.url}/create_channel_entry`,
      data: `channel_id=${entry.channel_id}&url_title=${entry.url_title}&title=${entry.title}&entry_date=${entry.entry_date}&session_id=${auth.session_id}`
    }
```

returns the correct response.
The other issue is just a correct mapping of the response with graphql schema.